# In Csharp, how do I count a certain value which increases everytime a specific button is clicked

Tags: variables, button, events, count, operators

Okay, so I am making this assignment where we have make a WPF app to do a certain calculation and once that calculation is done, you press a button to get the outcome of it. That outcome gets placed in a listbox. If you press the button multiple times, all the outcomes appear underneath eachother.

Now the issue I am having, there is another label which has to have a grand total of all the different outcomes. I however just cannot get it to work, I already asked for help to some peeps I know but to no avail. To me it always shows only the last outcome in that box and not the grand total, I have no idea how to make the script count a value multiple times when it has the same name, since it is a copy of the same label everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. I created a new double and set its value to be equal to itself + the value that is getting added.

```
double totalvalue = totalvalue + listboxvalue;
lblLabelname.Content = totalvalue;
```